# Storing date and time separately in NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, datetime-format

So i am getting a string containing date and time in this format `"2014-12-22T11:00:00+0500"` Now in order to convert it into NSdate i am using

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:start_time];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString* temp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
self.eventDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:temp];

NSDateFormatter* timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString* temp2 = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:date];
self.start_time = [timeFormatter dateFromString:temp2];
```

Now even though the conversion is successful the problem is that `eventDate` also has has time after date `00:00:00`. How can i remove this so that `eventDate` only contains date.

Conversly `start_time` has the time of event but also has some arbritrary reference date before that. How can i remove that so i only have time in `start_time`

I have searched hard and fast but haven't been able to figure out this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to use different date formatter for second format.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove either the date or the time to keep only one component. If I remember correctly NSDate object is internally just a number of seconds relative to a fixed point in time. So every NSDate contains the full date and time information.

What you probably want to do is to get the NSDateComponents you want from a NSDate object.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to store this separate, just display these dates separate. I think it could be useful sometimes to get the date completly, but i don't know your idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try with it, it may be help you.

NSString *finalDate = @"2014-12-22T11:00:00+0500";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:finalDate];

//For getting Time
NSDateFormatter* df1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df1 setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *time = [df1 stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"time  %@ ", time);

//For getting Date
NSDateFormatter* df2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *actualDate = [df2 stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"actualDate  %@ ", actualDate);
```